# Make a layer result from st_touches

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I executed a  query to know where a MultiLineString touches itself using st_touches from postgis as shown here :

```
select a.id,b.id ,a.geom,b.geom, ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom) 
from pipe AS a , pipe AS b 
where b.id > a.id and ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom) = true
```

yet the result is boolean (true or false).

I want to generate a point layer in each touching location. I tried to do create as select but it returned a table without geometry column.

How can I generate the point locations?

Comment: You did not include the `b.id > a.id` constraint from the answer to your previous question.

Comment: yes you're right. I'll edit my question

Comment: you need to use a function that does return a geometry in conjunction with the (boolean) st_touches; try replacing st_touches in your SELECT with st_intersection

Comment: thanks for your answer I used st_intersection with st_touches in condition this way : `create table touching_point3 as  SELECT  ST_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) FROM
pipe AS a INNER JOIN pipe AS b 
ON ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom) 
WHERE b.id > a.id  and ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom) = true`

Comment: You would need to restrict the dimension of the result, as st_intersection can return a line

Comment: @JGH true. among others, st_crosses instead of st_touches in the WHERE clause would be an easy alternative to guarantee only points (for line features).